# Show and hide element related div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, hover

I'm trying to implement a very simple javascript. I'm building some kind of a tooltip (a hidden `<div>` within the link) for when a link is hovered. 
So the thing is I have several links that have their own tooltip, with the code shown below the tooltips are correctly showing and hiding but the thing is I only want to show the tooltip related to that link only, not all of them. 
I think the good way to solve this is having one javascript function that only show the tooltip for that specific link and not having a function for each one of them.

Thanks in advance for any help, I hope I have explained my issue in a way you can understand.

```
 $(function() {
   $('.toolshoot').hover(function() {
       $('.toolbox').show();
   },       
   function () {
        $('.toolbox').hide();
     }
   );        
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this would work:

```
 $(function() {
   $('.toolshoot').hover(function() {
       $('.toolbox', this).show();
   },       
   function () {
        $('.toolbox', this).hide();
     }
   );        
 });
```

I'm searching for `.toolbox` inside of the element being hovered.

Next time please post a code sample with it's markup.

Comment: Worked like a breeze, code is very clean and nice so you get the answer as accepted. Thanks, thanks, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see your code and know exactly how the tooltip is "related" to the link but you may be able to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.toolshoot').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(':has(.toolbox)').find('.toolbox').show();
  },
  function () {
     $(this).closest(':has(.toolbox)').find('.toolbox').hide();
    }
  );
});
```